# Merging files when available in specified folder

Tags: python, merge, match, spss

I would like to merge different SPSS files to one new file. I plan to use the MATCH command in SPSS for this. See also another question from me on that topic ([Combining add cases and add variables by merging files in SPSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763480/combining-add-cases-and-add-variables-by-merging-files-in-spss/43765862#43765862)).

However, the number of files I want to merge automatically is not always the same. This depends on the data that a customer has been requested. On the other hand, each file will always be used in the same MATCH command.

For example, we have 7 files with data on health. When the customer has requested all data, all 7 files should be merged into one new file. However, when another customer has requested only data from 3 files, only these 3 files should be merged into one new file.

I am wondering if someone knows how I can achieve this. Maybe the files should be placed in a particular folder so that the existing files can be load/ match? The non-existing files should be ignored. Maybe a kind of 'if-then'-statement?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can generate and run a MATCH FILES command for all the files in a folder or all the files matching a wildcard name with a few lines of Python code.  Here is an example that merges all the sav files in a particular folder.

```
begin program.
import spss, glob

cmd = ["MATCH FILES"]

for f in glob.glob(r"c:/temp/*.sav"):
    cmd.append("""/FILE="%s" """ % f)
spss.Submit(cmd)
end program.
```

Comment: One would need to add whatever modifiers to the command as needed.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is the following. Might not be the most efficient way, but it works fine...

I suppose you have a file with a record for each customer, and 7 variables indicating the need for each of the files, like this:

```
data list /ID 1-3 (A) FIL1 to FIL7 5-11.
begin data
001 1100101
002 0100110
003 0011111
004 1111111
end data.
```

I always like the following old-fashioned approach. No macro's and no python!

```
str matchcommand (a2000).
compu matchcommand eq "match files".
do rep a = FIL1 to FIL7
      /b = "C:\fil1.sav" "C:\fil2.sav" "C:\fil3.sav" "C:\fil4.sav" 
           "C:\fil5.sav" "C:\fil6.sav" "C:\fil7.sav". 
if a matchcommand eq concat(matchcommand, "\n  /file='", b, "'").
end rep.

compu matchcommand eq concat(matchcommand, " /by id.")
```

The strings in matchcommand can be written to .sps file(s) using the `write`
command. If you add a save command to these pieces of syntax, you can easily call the syntax bits or files by using `insert file`.

Using Macros or Python is far more flexible than this approach. However, this one I always remember and I can jot it down in no-time. It might be rusty, but it's fast. That's why I like it so much.